# Can a Warlock have both a Sentinel Raven and a familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, familiars

I have a warlock player who chose Patron of the Raven Queen giving him *Sentinel Raven* and Pact of the Chain giving him *Find Familiar*. Is this fair? It seems almost like he has two familiars. The spell *Find Familiar* explicitly states:

> **You can't have more than one familiar at a time**. If you cast this spell while you already have a familiar, you instead cause it to adopt a new form. Choose one of the forms from the above list. Your familiar transforms into the chosen creature.

So, does the Sentinel Raven count as another familiar in this regard?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### The Raven is not a familiar.

Nothing in the Raven's write up indicates it a familiar or has that property. It quite specifically states:

> Starting at 1st level, you gain the service of a spirit sent by the Raven Queen to watch over you. The spirit assumes the form and game statistics of a raven, and it always obeys your commands, which you can give telepathically while it is within 100 feet of you.

While this, and several of its other features, are in common with familiars, the Raven is separate and distinct from a familiar in the same way a Ranger's Animal Companion is, or a Shield Guardian is.

Comment: No problem. My half-orc shaman (druid) has Ritual Caster and uses a Familiar and an Unseen Servant. I also use Animal Friendship and Speak with Animals to utilize wildlife in my service for whatever shenangians I feel like getting up to. Once I get Awaken, I'm going to have a walking, talking tree following me. I mean...... having a lot of companion creatures is hardly troubling to game balance.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli hope your druid has deep pockets. 1000gp per month to make awakened friends is expensive. And afterwards it is the DM's call if you get to keep them. It will remain friendly, but it is the same as Villager A: It has its own life to care for.

Comment: My Druid doesn't enslave Awakened friends. He treats them with kindness and respect. Example: My last awakened tree was gifted an Amulet of Fire Resistance to help with his vulnerabilities, and I used Plant Growth on him to bloom hundreds of flowers of his choosing and make him look beautiful. I then assigned him as a symbol of Agricultural yield after using Plant Growth again to enrich the crops of our city for a full year. I don't try to make infinite armies. I try to make stories.