# While merged with their Sentinel Raven using the Soul of the Raven feature, can a Raven Queen-patron Chainlock speak through their familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, familiars, unearthed-arcana

The Voice of the Chain Master [eldritch invocation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) allows a Pact of the Chain warlock to do the following (PHB, p. 111):

> You can communicate telepathically with your familiar and perceive
>   through your familiar's senses as long as you are on the same plane of
>   existence. Additionally, while perceiving through your familiar's
>   senses, you can also speak through your familiar in your own voice,
>   even if your familiar is normally incapable of speech.

Assume a Warlock has the Raven Queen as Patron (from [Unearthed Arcana: Warlock & Wizard](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/20170213_Wizrd_Wrlck_UAv2_i48nf.pdf#page=2)).

A Warlock with the Raven Queen patron can use the 6th-level Soul of the Raven feature to merge with the Sentinel Raven, as written:

> As a bonus action when your raven is perched on your shoulder, your
>   body merges with your raven’s form. While merged, you become Tiny, you
>   replace your speed with the raven’s, and you can use your action only
>   to Dash, Disengage, Dodge, Help, Hide, or Search. During this time,
>   you gain the benefits of your raven being perched on your shoulder.

Is it possible for a Warlock to communicate/speak through his/her familiar (e.g. a pseudodragon) with Voice of the Chain Master while merged with the Sentinel Raven via Soul of the Raven?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Usually is where I say to take the tour but you already did that. Interesting question, keep the good work.

Comment: Related: [Can a Warlock have both a Sentinel Raven and a familiar?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122523/can-a-warlock-have-both-a-sentinel-raven-and-a-familiar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Assuming you are talking about a familiar *other* than the raven<sup>1</sup>: yes

There is nothing in either ability that precludes the other.

As an aside, there is nothing about being merged that stops you speaking.

<sup>1</sup>Not that the raven is a [familiar](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122523/6203).